# PHP Curl Download Issues

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I have a function that takes as input an array of url's. I have verified that the url's are correct and I can loop through them perfectly. I also verified using curl_getinfo that curl is downloading the correct pages. However, the output of curl (html) is the same for every page. Here is my code:

```
          $urls = array();
     $urls = getpages($mainpage);
     print_r($urls);
     foreach($urls as $link) {
         echo $link. '<br><br><br>';
         $circdl = my_curl($link);
         echo $circdl. '<br><br><br>';
         $circdl = NULL;
     }
```

The outputted array of url's is as follows:

```
 Array ( [0] => http://www.site.com/savings/viewcircular?promotionId=81498&sneakpeek=&currentPageNumber=1 [1] => http://www.site.com/savings/viewcircular?promotionId=81498&sneakpeek=&currentPageNumber=2
```

$link also outputs appropriately as does curl in curl_getinfo. I have ran another array of url's thru this loop and they work fine but I suspect the issue here is with the format of the url (ampersands). I'm really stumped why these pages aren't downloading as expected.

Here's the my_curl function:

```
 function my_curl($url)
 {
$timeout=10;
$error_report=TRUE;
$curl = curl_init();
$cookiepath = drupal_get_path('module','mymodule'). '/cookies.txt';

// HEADERS AND OPTIONS APPEAR TO BE A FIREFOX BROWSER REFERRED BY GOOGLE
$header[] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: "; // BROWSERS USUALLY LEAVE BLANK

// SET THE CURL OPTIONS - SEE http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,            $url  );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6'  );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header  );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_REFERER,        'http://www.google.com'  );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING,       'gzip,deflate'  );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,    TRUE  );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE  );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE  );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,     $cookiepath );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,      $cookiepath );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        $timeout  );

// RUN THE CURL REQUEST AND GET THE RESULTS
$htm = curl_exec($curl);

// Check for page request

//$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
//echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];

// ON FAILURE HANDLE ERROR MESSAGE
if ($htm === FALSE)
{
    if ($error_report)
    {
        $err = curl_errno($curl);
        $inf = curl_getinfo($curl);
        echo "CURL FAIL: $url TIMEOUT=$timeout, CURL_ERRNO=$err";
        var_dump($inf);
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    return FALSE;
}

// ON SUCCESS RETURN XML / HTML STRING
curl_close($curl);
return $htm;
```

}

What's very interesting is that if I run this:

```
 echo my_curl('http://www.site.com/savings/viewcircular?promotionId=81498&sneakpeek=&currentPageNumber=2')
```

The output is correct!!??:(

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post the code for the `my_curl()` method as it appears to be the function holding the relevant code?

Comment: I just created an array with the two pages and ran it through the loop and it came out fine. The only difference that I can see is the $link variable is showing this: http://www.site.com/savings/viewcircular?promotionId=81498&sneakpeek=¤tPageNumber=1 instead of this http://www.site.com/savings/viewcircular?promotionId=81498&sneakpeek=&currentPageNumber=1. I definitely think this is an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was with the encoding of the url's being passed to my function. I mistakenly stripped the encoding and appended a "human-readable" end to the url. This caused the page to not be properly recognized by the host. How I fixed this was to ignore my better judgement and to leave the encoding alone. When the array is passed now the pages are loading correctly. Thanks for the all those who gave this a look. It really stumped me!

Here's a snippet of my code for explanation:

```
 function getpages($url) {
 global $host;
 $circdl = my_curl($url);
 $circqp = htmlqp($circdl,'body');
 //Extract last page number
 $lastpagenumber = $circqp->branch()->find('li[class="last-page"]')->text();
 $lastpagenumberurl = $circqp->branch()->find('li[class="last-page"]')->children('a')->attr('href');  
 //Extract page link root
 $pagelinkroot = substr_replace($lastpagenumberurl,"",-2);
 $currentpage = "=";               
 $lpn = intval($lastpagenumber);

 //Move through the remaining pages
 $pagelinks = array();
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $lpn; ++$i) {
   $pagelinks[] = join(array($host,$pagelinkroot,$currentpage,$i));
   }
   return $pagelinks;
 }
```

Substr_replace was used to stip down the ecoding. I changed this from 20 to 2 to just strip the end off and then append it after the loop thru the links.